# Convert video data to URL for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata

I'm trying to take an NSData representation of a video file written with AVAssetWriter and play it in an instance of MPMoviePlayerController without having to write the NSData to file.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
video_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
video_player.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
video_player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:videoData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
[video_player setContentURL:dataURL];
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this that works? Thanks!